# Html show scroll only if bigger than max-height

Tags: html, css

I wanna show scroll only if is bigger than max-height. But it seems the scroll is always enable

```html
<div style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.5rem; max-height: 7rem; overflow-y: auto;">
  Some text
</div>
```

image example in my case

[image]

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code, as per your code yes if the content grows more thatn `7rem` you will see a scroll. also you should use `vh` for the relative height not `rem` this is for fontsize.

Comment: I correct it.. I changed max-height with height and seem works

Comment: Not necessary, you can still have max-height and have same thing. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/3zshy8r0/34/

Comment: so do you suggest to use vh instead rem?

Comment: Yes, I just added it as answer, I will add reference link as well. Check the link that will give you what kinds of units used for what purpose, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vh` rather than using `rem` which is meant for `font-size` not for relative height:

[Unit-Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

```css
div {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  max-height: 10vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Some text Before Oracle9 if I had "select any table" privileges there was no problem doing so. ... allow direct access to the v$ tables, do not allow access by stored procedures ... I don't think O7_DICTIONARY_ACCESSIBILITY provides access to sys.link$
  ... Before Oracle9 if I had "select any table" privileges there was no problem doing so. ... allow direct access to the v$ tables, do not allow access by stored procedures ... I don't think O7_DICTIONARY_ACCESSIBILITY provides access to sys.link$ ...
  https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/3zshy8r0/34/ Before Oracle9 if I had "select any table" privileges there was no problem doing so. ... allow direct access to the v$ tables, do not allow access by stored procedures ... I don't think O7_DICTIONARY_ACCESSIBILITY
  provides access to sys.link$ ...
</div>
```